# Ansible does not run playbook with -u root

Tags: ansible

I have a weird problem. when I run a playbook with the -u root option it does not run on the remote machine. My colleagues are able to run it as root with the -u root option.

Weirdest thing is that I can ssh to the remote machine. I can sudo to root on the machine and I am able to run playbooks without the -u root option there.

It must be some kind of configuration thing but I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find it. Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the documentation. The `-u` means you want to connect to the server as a root user so you should have configured ssh keys or you should add a `--become` flag to able pass the password for root user.

```
 Connection Options:
    control as whom and how to connect to hosts

-u REMOTE_USER, --user=REMOTE_USER
                        connect as this user (default=None)
```

Comment: Weird thing is....ssh keys are configured. The --become is handled in the playbook.